# "Smacking" vs "smacking up" vs "smacking around"

Tags: phrase-usage

"Smacking" vs "smacking up" vs "smacking around"

What's the difference between the three? Which is more common?

> I was at school, **smacking a** douche who called me a nerd.
>
> I was at school, **smacking up** a douche who called me a nerd.
>
> I was at school, **smacking around** a douche who called me a nerd.

Comment: You sound as though you are just back from Ireland. The word I think you need is *three*, rather than *tree*.

Comment: "Smack" has multiple diverse meanings, and the usage is quite idiomatic and will tend to be culture-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Smacking around"** is the best usage for your example - it implies a physical altercation.

**"Smacking,"** in the same sentence is a bit odd - in AmE if the beating is ongoing, one would use "smacking around," or **"giving some douche *a smacking*,"** as a single blow wouldn't detain you very long.

"Smack up" is not used in the same way.  Unless you say "smacking *him/her* up" it might be misunderstood, as **"smack-up"** is a term most commonly used for vehicular accidents.

From an onlooker's point of view: "Some nerd and some douche had a **smack-down**."

Answer (score 1):

"Smacking" most commonly refers to corporal punishment of a child by someone who has some sort of right to do so. Apparently in the US *spank* is more common in this context, while in BrEn a *light smack* is a possibility and *spank* (unmodified) implies a harder blow than *smack* and quite possibly more blows as well.

"Smacking around" gives the impression of a strong person hitting a weaker, even defenceless, individual. Like "smacking up" a common sense might be domestic abuse.

Because "smack" also means heroin, "smack up" can also mean to take heroin.

While any of them (especially "smacking around") might work if you want to signify dominance as well as violence, to me none of them works very well. But maybe that says more about my background. You might have a look at urban dictionary for this sort of query, but always with a slightly sceptical mind.

Comment: I agree with this answer too.

Comment: I've never heard "smacking" for corporal punishment in American English.  The usual term is "spanking."  If someone said they had "smacked" their child, you'd probably think of calling children's services, regardless of your position on corporal punishment.

Comment: @ChrisSunami, that's interesting - I'll edit in a note to the effect that it may be commonwealth-specific (the online dictionaries don't have much to say on this, except wiktionary has a note that *spank* is the US equivalent, and *smack is used in NZ) .

Answer (score -1):

There is no need for commas in your sentence examples.  2nd example is definitely not good.  Both 1 and 3 are ok, grammatically speaking (especially without the comma).

I assume the 2nd example comes from the similarity of "beating up" someone.  I have never heard smacking in this context.

Smacking around would imply multiple smacks.  First example could be said, even if you smacked only once.

Comment: I don’t see why the second one is “definitely not good”. It seems perfectly fine to me, if a bit Prodigal. There’s nothing wrong with the commas either, though they’re not _necessary_, of course.

Comment: I just never heard the expression "smacking up", so I said it is not good because people are likely not going to know what you are talking about.

Comment: You never heard “Change my pitch up / smack my bitch up”?

Comment: I am not so in touch with the latest ghetto slang, so if that is your audience, I'm not your expert.

Comment: It's the chorus of a (very well-known) song from 1997, sampling a 1989 song with the same wording. A phrase that's been in use for over 25 years is hardly the latest ghetto slang. While _smack up_ is more colloquial than _beat up_, it's still a perfectly common phrasing to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I agree, but the song was by Prodigy not Prodigal, and, as a female, I found the phrase smack my bitch up offensive - I seem to recall a fair amount of protest at the time. And yes, it has now passed into urban use, though I don't hear it so much now.

Comment: @bamboo I was using ‘Prodigal’ as the adjectival form of _Prodigy_. Yes, it was offensive (and probably meant to be, despite their claims to the opposite), but that's more to do with the message it seemingly bears than the phrase _smack up_. In the context given in this question, it's clearly not offensive, just fairly wankerish.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Agreed on all points! Just 'rap' type slang really. But there is a band called Prodigal as well...